# Yii Controller Parameters

Tags: yii

When I create this method

```
actionTest($parameter){
    print($parameter);
}
```

inside of a yii controller and attempt to access it in the browser I get an error 400.

How can I set up yii so that if I enter:
/controller/test/text  it would simply print the string 'text' on the screen instead of returning an invalid request error?

I already verified that the URL is correct. If I write

```
actionTest(){
  print('text'); 
}
```

and then go to /controller/test/text then it works just fine.

How can I set up yii so that a controller action can accept parameter values in the URL?

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit the `urlManager` rewrite rules array in your `config.php` to include

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    ....
    'rules'=>array(
        'controller/test/<parameter:\w+>' => 'controller/test',
        ...
    ),
),
```

with your controller function as

```
actionTest($parameter){
   print($parameter);
}
```

Comment: That did not work. Is there something that I can do to add this feature to any controller with parameters?

Comment: Thanks. That helped!!! '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'

Answer (score 1):

> @curtis: Thanks. That
>   helped!!! `<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>`
>   –  Curtis Colly Mar 31 '13 at 3:27

The rule `<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>` line will send the last parameter to the controller as `$id` if you want to use $parameter you should change id to parameter.

```
<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<parameter:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>
```

In the controller you can also type

```
actionTest(){
    print($_GET['parameter']); //or $_REQUEST
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the url: `/controller/test/parameter/text` , it should work.
Suggested url rule by @topher is also correct.